# What is the difference javascript:method() and just plain method()

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have come across the following syntax in JavaScript

```
<img style="padding-left:8px;" id="testIcon" align="middle" src="/images/test.png" onclick="javascript:testMethod()"/>
```

and was wondering what is the difference between above and

```
<img style="padding-left:8px;" id="testIcon" align="middle" src="/images/test.png" onclick="testMethod()"/>
```

Comment: I'd guess that the former syntax is available because some browsers support scripting languages other than JavaScript.  IE supports VBScript, for instance.

Comment: @nix your comment seems to be an answer.

Comment: Off-topic: using inline event listeners is a bad practice. Better add listers with JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the pseudo-protocol `javascript` comes from a time when it was used in the `href` attribute of an anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething()">Click me</a>
```

In the above context the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol gives a hint to the browser than this is a function to run, not an address to resolve.

In that context of your question:

```
<img src="images/test.png" onclick="javascript:testMethod()"/>
```

it does nothing.

The `javascript:` is treated as a label (a little-known part of the JavaScript language) and is harmless.  Since the browser knows that `onclick` calls a script, nothing special *is* needed.

Comment: At least in the context of the `href` attribute, "javascript:something" is a JavaScript URI.  The "javascript:" is the URI scheme, not some sort of label within the JavaScript language.

Comment: Correct, @nix, which is why I used the term `pseudo-protocol` since there is no official `javascript:` protocol.

Comment: It's a happy coincidence that the same code worked in both attributes. Wasn't sure if it was a language feature (label) or codified preservation of bad developer behavior.

Comment: @BrianNickel I'd put it down to "cargo-cult" programming.  Somebody saw it done somewhere and just copied it without understand why or what it did.  Alas, JavaScript suffers from a lot of that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that the former syntax is available because some browsers support scripting languages other than JavaScript. IE supports VBScript, for instance.  If you had a page containing JavaScript and VBScript functions with the same name, you could probably use that syntax to disambiguate.

Comment: Okay tx for the repy. Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: I looked at the HTML 4.01 and 5 specifications and didn't find anything about `javascript:` URIs or anything that looks like them in event handlers.  There may be something that I missed, or it may be something non-standard that some browsers do.